# laravel gates permission foreach

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-permission

excuse me, i'm a junior developer and im still learn about laravel gates concept. i have a tables structure like this.

1. Users = id, email, password, role_id.
2. role = id, name, description.
3. permission = id, name, slug.
4. role_permission = permission_id, role_id.
   and this is my code

   $permission = Permission::all();

   ```
    foreach($permission as $p){
        Gate::define($p->slug, function(User $user) use ($p) {
            return $user->role_id === ???;
        });
    }
   ```

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt0kJ.jpg)

what should i return to protect gates, thanks.

im still learning about laravel gates concept, so i hope the other senior developers help me to explain about gates

Comment: Take a look at this package: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction

Check the documentation and the implementation of it. It has a very good way to handle permissions. If it's possible for you, you could use it and save you some time with the detailed implementation.